# How to tell JQuery where to place new content

Tags: jquery

I have a simple messaging system (like on Facebook) which contains `New` messages, and also `Replies` to a message. The HTML is really simple:

```
<div id="messages">
<ol class="new-messages">
     <li id="message45"><p>A new message</p>
       <ol class="replies-messages">
         <li><p>A reply to the message</p></li>
       </ol>
     </li>
    <li id="message46"><p>Another new message</p>
     </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

When a new message is posted, its done by AJAX to the server. The server will then return some JSON like this:

```
{"Message":[{"MessageBody":"<p>A message here</p>", "InReplyToMessageID":"45"}]}
```

So given the above JSON, it seems this new message to be added to the DOM is actually a reply to message 45. I know in my HTML that there is a list item with an id of `message45` so I would like this new message to be prepended to the `<ol class="replies-messages">` ordered list which is nested within the `<li id="message45">` list item.

If the `InReplyToMessageID` value is blank, then its a new message and should instead be prepended to the `<ol class="new-messages">` ordered list instead.

Is this even possible using JQuery? I fear the logic is so complicated I should probably try a different technology but I'm not sure what would be suitable for this task. I can only, so far, seem to be able to append to one of the lists:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/messageurl',
                data: $("form").serializeArray(),
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (result) {

            $.each(result.Message, function (index, value) {
           $("#messages > ol").prepend('<li>' + value.MessageBody + '</li>');               
});

                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("Please try again.");
                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this is right up jQuery's alley. Something like this should work:

```
var target;

if (msg.InReplyToMessageId == "") {
  target = $('.new_messages');
} else {
  target = $('li#message' + msg.InReplyToMessageId).find('.replies-messages');
}

var newMessage = $('<li>');
newMessage.html(msg.MessageBody);
newMessage.attr('id', /* ... */);
target.prepend(newMessage);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what JQuery does well. I thought this was the main reason for using JQuery in the first place was to handle examples like this.

Comment: In this case, how does JQ provide any advantage over standard JS and `getElementById()`? Seems like JS would be more readable, even.

Comment: Well, technically everything you use JQuery to do can be done just as well with normal JS. It's about semantics and abstractions for me. I think $('#id') is much easier to see and understand and even to explain than getElementById('id') but really, it is opinion. I've done it both ways, sometimes on the same project.

Comment: @WanderNauta I'm getting a warning on the `target.prepend(newMessage)` bit. It says "target used out of scope".

Comment: @volumeone Ah yes. Should be fixed now.